# How to generate a colorbar for manually colored plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I need to control line colors myself for some reason, for example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    plt.plot([i,i+1,i+2], color=mpl.cm.viridis(i))
```

How to generate a colorbar for such a plot？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create a colorbar without any reference axes. This can be done with the `matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase` class. See also [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) from the gallery. 
To use this, you need to create a new axis in the plot, where the colorbar should sit in; one way of doing this is to use `make_axes_locatable`.

Here is a complete example.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np


for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 9):
    plt.plot([i,i+1,i+2], color=mpl.cm.viridis(i))

divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
ax_cb = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.05)    
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_cb, cmap=mpl.cm.viridis, orientation='vertical')
plt.gcf().add_axes(ax_cb)

plt.show()
```

[image]